# Importing contents of files with dodgy names in php

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Is there anyway to get the contents of files with names like those below into a php script :: `@file_get_contents()` isn't working.

```
/pictures/308/general/big/VILLA ROSE (22).jpg
```

and 
/pictures/308/general/big/VILLA ROSE (22).jpg

Comment: It should be working with names as these as well. If you remove the `@` in front of the function call, you might be able to tell us the error message. *isn't working* isn't working as a description.

Comment: Strange that it is only filenames like that which are not being picked up out of over 3000, which is why I thought it would be some common solution. Thanks for your understanding and Bah Humbug to you in the season of goodwill to all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up with this, where $va holds the image src:

```
$va = explode(".com/",$va);
$sh = rawurlencode($va[1]);
$va = $va[0] . ".com/" . $sh;
$imgcont = @file_get_contents($va);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$filename = "test/VILLA ROSE (22).jpg";
$x = file_get_contents($filename);
var_dump($x);
die();
```

Check if your absolute path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

See:

http://blog.unitedheroes.net/curl/

http://phpsense.com/php/php-curl-functions.html

http://devzone.zend.com/article/1081

http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-tutorial-and-example/

For image specific use:

http://www.bitrepository.com/download-image.html

http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/php/php-save-images-using-curl/

Its difficult to be more precise without knowledge of what you're trying to achieve